# CheckboxFor - Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried many solutions but none of them worked for me. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

View Code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => @Model.Rate.AvailYesNo,new { @checked = "checked" })
```

Model:

```
public bool? AvailYesNo { get; set; } = false;
```

Error:

> CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I try GetValueorDefault, I get this error
"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. "

Comment: The error is clear. You tried to pass a `bool?` to a bool variable or parameter. You have to convert that `bool?` to a `bool` somehow. What do you want to do if `AvailYesNo` is null?

Comment: Panagiotis, if it is null, I want to convert it to false, can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of the nullable boolean to just boolean, as it will never be null given you assign a default value regardless.

That will also resolve your issue on the view.

```
public bool AvailYesNo { get; set; } = false;
```